# What is the best way to separate a single list into multiple lists based on a pattern in Python?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have an unstructured list as an input which I need to flatten before I run several analysis on them. Once I have the results for each input what it the best way to put them back in the same structure of the original list?

```
inputList = [["a", ["b","c","d"], [["e"]], "f"],["g"]]

flattenedList = myFlattenListFunction(inputList)

# a number of calculations based on the inputList
# ...

flattenedResults = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

#What is the best solution to restructure the results to match the inputLists?
[[1, [2,3,4], [[5]], 6], [7]]
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about the calculations? Might it be possible to not do the flattening?

Comment: `chain` will not flatten arbitrarily nested list (eg the `["e"]`)

Comment: @donkopotamus well yeah, keep in mind that `chain.from_iterable([anything])` will only give you `anything`

Comment: @donkopotamus and Adam - Thanks. You're right, I edited the question so it doesn't cause distraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using a Queue for the output values and recursion:

```
def copyStruct(inputStruct, outputValues):
    return [copyStruct(subList, outputValues)
            if isinstance(subList, list)
            else next(outputValues)
            for subList in inputStruct]

copyStruct(inputList, iter(flattenedResults))
```

Comment: equivalent to mine. No need to use a queue here, just use an iterator and `next(output_values)`!

Comment: Ah! Thanks @Adam Smith for the tip on the iterator, but I think this is a bit cleaner than using nested functions.

Comment: To each their own :) I prefer seeing a clean closure rather than a messy list comp. Either way it works great

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are good for this. Keep a copy of your original list around so you maintain its structure, then construct an iterator of your flattened list, recurse over your original list (or a copy of it) and replace each element with the next element out of the iterator

```
import copy

inputList = [["a", ["b","c","d"], [["e"]], "f"],["g"]]
flat_results = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

def replace(orig, repl):
    new = copy.deepcopy(orig)
    repl = iter(repl)
    def _replace(lst):
        for idx, el in enumerate(lst):
            if isinstance(el, list):
                _replace(el)
            else:
                lst[idx] = next(repl)
    _replace(new)
    return new

replace(inputList, flat_results)
# [[0, [1, 2, 3], [[4]], 5], [6]]
```

Comment: You could probably do this in one function with judicious use of default arguments.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Probably, but I don't see anything wrong with the closure. Makes it look cleaner IMO

Answer (score 0):

```
inputList = [["a", ["b","c","d"], [["e"]], "f"],["g"]]
flattenedList = magic(inputList)  # in python2, `magic` is compiler.ast.flatten

flatResults = calculations(flattenedList)

# now for the fun stuff

resultify(inputList, flatResults)

def resultify(inputList, flatResults, answer=None):
    if answer is None: answer = []
    if not inputList: return answer
    for elem in inputList:
        if not isinstance(elem, list): answer.append(flatResults.pop(0))
        else: answer.append(resultify(elem, flatResults, []))
    return answer
```

Output:

```
In [29]: inputList = [["a", ["b","c","d"], [["e"]], "f"],["g"]]

In [30]: flatResults = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

In [31]: resultify(inputList, flatResults)
Out[31]: [[1, [2, 3, 4], [[5]], 6], [7]]
```